# check if result from shell command is an executable office file

Tags: ruby

I need to retrieve soffice executable that belongs to LibreOffice. Now if you have OpenOffice installed on system, its name may also be soffice. I need to ignore that one. I want to check if the return value of the shell command is executable and belongs to LibreOffice. This is what I have:

```
executable = `ls $(which soffice)`
=> "/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS//soffice\n"
```

For some strange reason it says it does not exist and is not executable:

```
Dir.chdir('/')
f = File.open executable
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS//soffice
> File.exists? executable
=> false 
> File.executable? executable
=> false
```

How can I check if the returned path is executable and belongs to LibreOffice?

Comment: I think your problem is the \n at the end the name. Try removing that before using it in the call to File.exists? For example: File.exists? executable.gsub("\n","")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're not pointing to the correct file? Look carefully at the file path you're using:

```
"/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS//soffice\n"
```

Trailing `"\n"` is suspicious and would be treated as a significant character. And, that's the result of not using `chomp` on the output of a back ticks command:

```
`ls '/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2'`
# => "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2\n"
`ls '/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2'`.chomp
# => "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2"
```

On my system I can see things like:

```
File.exist?('/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2') # => true
File.executable?('/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2') # => true
```

On Mac OS, there are some file names that will have a trailing `\r`, so you have to be aware that you can't blindly strip off line-end characters.

Comment: Yeah using strip with it worked File.executable? executable.strip

Comment: `strip` isn't necessary. Its purpose is to remove trailing whitespace from both ends of a string. Instead, `chomp` will remove trailing line-ends. There's a tiny speed difference.